# React needs web server? How do the web application server and react communicate?

Tags: reactjs, web, https, frontend, was

I'm a student who study web development by myself.
I'm developing a shopping mall site as my personal project and I've got some elemental questions when I tried to make a login page.

First of all, I will tell you about the main concepts of my project on the beginning for you to understand my questions more easily.

My initial concepts and ideas are in below :

- Database(MySQL) 
  I needed some data to show on the web site. So I decided to use 'Fashion Product Images Dataset' on the Kaggle. Users who sign up will be stored as well.
  I just assumed that there is everything that I need, in order to make the website.
- Web Application Server(API server)
  I thought this is a kind of bridge which are able to make the javaScript on the browser to get some resources, a sort of product images and prices, when the page is loaded for the first time or the resources need to be changed by users or codes.
- Web Server(Built-in the React)
  I made the React application using 'create-react-app', so I don't need to think about the web server actually. The only thing that I have done is building some components which display the UI using react library.

```
FRONT-END                                      BACK-END
 ----------          ----------------------------------------------------------------
|  CLIENT  | < --- > |   REACT   | < --- > |  API-SERVER  | < --- > |  DATABASE  |
|   REACT  |         |(WEB-SERVER)|
```

When users request my page, React(The built-in server) reply it.
Then, the users will get the SPA(client-side).

The SPA doesn't have any data, it will fetch the data from the API server(Because fetching codes are inserted in the .js files).
Then, The query inside of the api server will get the data from the database.
And then, the API server gives the data to the SPA.

It was quite going well until I start to think about the security. As you can see, when we visit other web sites, they use the https not the http. So I wanted to use the https, because it is really important to protect personal data from bad people. When I consider my idea, but, there wasn't any place to put the code which changes http to https.

Plus, I understood React is just a library, like reactjs.org said. So I think the reason why I am able to use the built-in web server is because the application is made by 'create-react-app'.

Finally, here are main questions.
As I know, the https logic should be in the web server. I mean the server which deal with the client's request.

1. If what the react is a library is true, do I have to build a web server?
   (I think building a web server by Node.js or other languages is the right way, because a library is just a library..!)
2. If I don't need to build a web server, where should I put the logic?
3. Let's imagine that I am totally ready to use https (I made a web server by Node.js and I got a CA to use TLS), and then, the client and the web server are able to communicate safely. But, all of the code which call the API are written in the .js files.
   And the files are now the client's browser. It means client and the API server doesn't have safe connection, because the API server and web server have different domain or port.

Maybe summary of the question 3:
3.1. When I searched on google, I understood web application server is to deal with requests that web server can not service. In the SPA, but, the request is from the client. Is this right?

3.1.1. If the question from the client, how to prove it is safe communication between client and web application server? because web server and web application server have different domain or port!

Comment: Hi Goldfish. Your question has attracted many downvotes, which usually indicates a quality problem. The current question includes too much context and speculation, and then fires off many questions - most of which already have excellent quality answers available. I believe your line of thinking is actually very commendable, but stream-of-consciousness doesn't work in a Q&A format.  It's likely this question will end up deleted by moderation, so I recommend you get in front, remove it yourself, and read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before reposting.

Comment: I am so sorry, this was my first posting and I'm not good at English. That's why there are many problems, sorry again.
I will delete it as soon as I save the answer from Quentin

Comment: I can't delete it myself, so I flagged that this is too much option-based question. Please delete it...

Comment: Most likely blocked by having an accepted answer. Your alternative is to rewrite it as succinct and clear question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> there wasn't any place to put the code which changes http to https.

Somewhere you have code which makes an HTTP request to a URL to fetch data from the API. That code *must* state what the URL is. You can specify the URL scheme there.

> So I think the reason why I am able to use the built-in web server is because the application is made by 'create-react-app'.

React is a JS library. It doesn't have a built-in web server. `create-react-app` installs React, generates some default project files, and **includes lots of tooling**.

The web server is intended for development use only. It includes features that are useful for development but inefficient for production such as Hot Reloading.

It also has a [build script](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/) that outputs static files for deploying on your production web server.

Your production server can support HTTPS. It may or may not be the same server that hosts your API.

Comment: `The web server is intended for development use only`  
It means that if I want to make a web page for public usage, do I need to make another web server? not the default one? 
`Your production server can support HTTPS.`  
In order to make my web server to support HTTPS, I have to use a kind of `https` module in the web server. like `const https = require('https');`

Comment: You don't have to write your own server. An off-the-shelf one is perfectly fine. Nginx for example, or even an Amazon S3 bucket configured for static hosting.

Comment: I am still curious about that if I want to save users data in the database, for example login, the id and password will go to a server. In this case, the server will be web application server, is this right?
Tthe data will be passed using `http` protocol. when the web server and API server have different domain, how this data is encrypted?

Comment: "The data will be passed using http protocol" — only if you choose to use HTTP instead of HTTPS … in which case it won't be encrypted (unless you roll your own encryption layout … which you shouldn't (just use HTTPS)).

Comment: Oh, Yes! That's the point!.
I want to use HTTPS. When I searched the basic process of HTTP over the TLS(HTTPS), the client and server have to share a public key. ah, the web server and web application server have a same key...?? I'm so sorry

Comment: Install a certificate. Configure the web server to use it. That's it. (https://howhttps.works/the-handshake/ if you want the details of what happens between the browser and the server, but you don't need to care)

Comment: Thank you so much!